# Justification for proportionality in Hubble's law

Tags: cosmology, astrophysics, astronomy

I just read about the Hubble's law which states that the speed $v$ (related to a point $A$, let's say the center of Earth) of a galaxy and its distance D (to the same point $A$) are proportional: $v = H_0 D$.

What is the justification to explain that those two quantities should be proportional?

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann%E2%80%93Lema%C3%AEtre%E2%80%93Robertson%E2%80%93Walker_metric).

Answer (score 0):

Experimental evidence suggests
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubble%27s_law.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the justification is that that's what Hubble observed. When you get past Hubble's law and start working out the theory, it comes down to the statement: the rate at which objects that are comoving with the expansion of the universe separates is proportional to the distance between them. If the Hubble parameter were constant in time, and not just space, that would mean that space would expand exponentially. That, too, is exactly what you would expect if the expansion were driven by a local process. A similar example: if you uniformly heat a rod, the total change in length of the rod is proportional to the initial length of the rod.

Given that analogy, it shouldn't come as a surprise that the Hubble parameter plays a direct role in the [Friedmann equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann_equations).